# Tabulator: How to provide my own custom pagination footer and have Tabulator page the data?

Tags: tabulator

I want Tabulator to perform all the pagination for me locally but want to provide my own custom pagination controls. If set the **footerElement** to my custom pagination panel Tabulator displays it correctly but does not page the data. I have to also set these additional properties for it to page the data correctly:

```
pagination: 'local',
paginationSize: 25
```

However, with these additional properties set, it displays both my custom pagination panel as well as Tabulators own implementation.

Is there a way of achieving what I need?

I am using:

- "react-tabulator": "^0.13.1"
- "tabulator-tables": "^4.7.1"

Alternatively, is there a way to include a rows indicator within the Tabulator pagination that displays something like:

> 1-25 of 80

The above indicates that we are displaying rows 1 to 25 out of a total of 80 rows.

Comment: Has anyone been able to successfully use a set of custom pagination controls via the footerElement?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to replace the table footer with  your own element using the ***footerElement*** option:

```js
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    footerElement:"<div class='table-footer><button>Custom Button</button></div>", //add a custom button to the footer element
});
```

Checkout the [Footer Element Documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.7/layout#footer) for full details

Alternatively you could use a little CSS to hide the table footer by setting the ***.tabulator-footer*** class to `display:none;`

Comment: Do I need to do something special to enable onClick event in the footerElement? Button does not seem to work (I use react-tabulator).

Comment: That would depend on usage case. You would surely want the click on an element inside the footer as the footer element itself is just a containing div

Comment: I tried some variants and it seems to be a limitation of jsx syntax when using react-tabulator. The click event of the button works if I use plain tabulator and jsfiddle. It also works with react-tabulator, if I specify the footerElement as a string and use escaped strings inside it: footerElement= {"<button onclick=\"alert('clicked')\">Click me</button>"} With jsx syntax the button is shown but I did not get the event working: footerElement= <button onClick={()=>alert('clicked')}>Click me</button>

Comment: Related react-tabulator issue: https://github.com/ngduc/react-tabulator/issues/212